# Переопределение класса-наследника

Tags: c#, классы

```
class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public Person(string fname, string lname)
    {
        FirstName = fname;
        LastName = lname;
    }

    public virtual void Display()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(FirstName + " " + LastName);
    }
}

class Employee : Person
{
    public string Company { get; set; }

    public Employee(string fname, string lname, string comp) : base(fname, lname)
    {
        Company = comp;
    }

    public override void Display()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(FirstName + " " + LastName + " работает в компании " + Company);
    }
}

class Demo
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Person p1 = new Person("Bill", "Gates");
        p1.Display();

        Person p2 = new Employee("Tom", "Johns", "UnitBank");
        p2.Display();

        Employee p3 = new Employee("Sam", "Toms", "CreditBank");
        p3.Display();

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Есть несколько вопросов по данному коду.

1. В классе Employee метод Display() можно переопределить, а можно с помощью оператора new сделать явное сокрытие метода Display() из класса Person. В чем разница между сокрытием и переопределением и что в каких-либо ситуациях лучше использовать?
2. Почему при переопределении метода в классе Employee при создании объекта p2 вызывается метод класса Employee, а при сокрытии метода объект p2 будет обращаться к методу Display() из класса Person?
3. Фрагмент:

   ```
   Person p2 = new Employee("Tom", "Johns", "UnitBank");
   p2.Display();
   ```

   В данном случае был создан объект p2 класса Person, ссылающийся на конструктор класса Employee. Меня интересует зачем при создании объекта p2 присваивать ссылку на конструктор класса наследника. Ведь в классе Person нет поля, хранящее информацию где работает сотрудник, зачем же тогда вызывать конструктор класса Employee?

Comment: "В данном случае был создан объект p2 класса Person" - был создан объект `Employee` и ссылка на него занесена в переменную `p2` базового типа `Person`.

Answer (score 2):

1. Разница в том, что именно будет выполнено при вызове через ссылку на базовый класс. Если методы определены через `virtual`/`override`, будет вызван метод класса `Employee`. А если метод переопределён через `new`, будет всё равно вызван метод класса `Person`. Что собственно и сказано в вашем вопросе номер 2.
2. Вызов виртуального метода всегда вызывает самое «новое» его перекрытие. По сути, вызов будет произведён так, как будто заявленный тип объекта соответствует реальному (по есть как будто бы `p2` имело тип `Employee`).

   Вызов невиртуального метода происходит в соответствии с заявленным типом. Поскольку заявленный тип `p2` — `Person`, будут вызваны лишь методы, «видимые» в `Person`.
3. В данном случае это не обязательно. Но существуют более сложные сценарии, при которых вы не знаете точного типа объекта. Например, в зависимости от условия может быть сконструирован экземпляр `Person` или `Employee`. Поскольку `Employee` является `Person` (но не наоборот), то с ними можно работать одинаковым образом (например, используя виртуальные функции). Это позволит не писать код в стиле `if (это Employee) { обработка для Employee } else if (это Manager) { обработка для Manager } else ...`.